# How to avoid the user can to write on DropdownMenu in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to avoid the user can to type on the **DropdownMenu** Widget, but I cannot find how to do that. I was looking for in the api.flutter.dev, But I did not find anything.I would appreciate the help.

```
class TDSMDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final String? value;
  final String? hintText;
  final String? label;
  final void Function(String?)? onSelected;
  final TextEditingController? controller;

  const TDSMDropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    this.value,
    this.hintText,
    required this.label,
    this.onSelected,
    this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TDSMDropdown> createState() => _TDSMDropdownState();
}

class _TDSMDropdownState extends State<TDSMDropdown> {
  // final TextEditingController colorController = TextEditingController();
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedValue = widget.value;
  }

  _handleOnSelected(String? newVal) {
    widget.onSelected!(newVal);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownMenu<String>(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      enableSearch: false,
      // controller: colorController,
      label: widget.label == null ? null : Text(widget.label!),
      dropdownMenuEntries: widget.items
          .map((e) => DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: e, label: e))
          .toList(),
      // inputDecorationTheme: _decoration(),
      onSelected: widget.onSelected != null ? _handleOnSelected : null,
    );
  }
```

**Information**

- Flutter version 3.7.0
- Material 3
- dart 2.19.0

Attached the image of the current behavior. Currently I can write on the dropdown input, I do not want that.

[image]

I need the same behavior that the DropdownButton2 package has.

[image]

Comment: can you include the screenshot of what you want to achieve

Comment: I'd like to know more about what you consider "type" is. As far as I know, Dropdowns are for tapping, instead of typing

Comment: @MunsifAli thanks for answering. I attach the screenshot

Comment: @LuisUtrera excuse me for my English, with "typing", I want to say write. thanks for answering

Comment: ‘I need to avoid the user can to type’ — that’s ungrammatical and I have no idea what it means.

Comment: @user3840170 thanks, bro. I already changed the title of the question.

Comment: Is there any issue with using DropdownButton class from Flutter sdk?

Comment: @Rahul yeah bro, there is. I need the dropdown to appear under the dropdown button, as I show in the post pictures.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DropdownButtonFormField widget for this here is the example

```
 DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                label: Text("Role"),
              ),
              value: 0,
              items: [
                const DropdownMenuItem(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  value: 0,
                  enabled: false,
                  child: Text("Select Your role"),
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 1,
                  child: const Text("Admin"),
                  onTap: () {
                    role = "Admin";
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 2,
                  child: const Text("Miner"),
                  onTap: () {
                    role = "Miner";
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 3,
                  child: const Text("Polisher"),
                  onTap: () {
                    role = "Polisher";
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 4,
                  child: const Text("Certifier"),
                  onTap: () {
                    role = "Certifier";
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 5,
                  child: const Text("Q/A"),
                  onTap: () {
                    role = "Q/A";
                  },
                ),
              ],
              onChanged: (value) {
                value = value;
              },
            ),
```

which will give you this result

[image]